# Extracting nested json object from json in freemarker

Tags: json, parsing, freemarker

```
<#assign test='{ "apple": 5, "banana": {"kiwi": 15 }}'?eval>
```

I need to extract banana object , tried like below but it's getting error out.

```
${test.banana}
```

Error 
For "${...}" content: Expected a string or something automatically convertible to string (number, date or boolean), or "template output" , but this has evaluated to an

```
extended_hash (wrapper: f.c.HashLiteral$SequenceHash):
==> test.banana  [in nameless template at line 2, column 3]
```

---

```
FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
    - Failed at: ${test.banana}  [in nameless template at line 2, colum
```

Answer (score 2):

These are the ways you can access.
Input

```
    <#assign test = { "apple": "5", "banana": {"kiwi": 15 }} >

Directly access your key and display the value. (if you know the key)

    ${test.banana.kiwi}

Dynamically list the keys

    <#list test.banana?keys as k>
    ${k}
    </#list>

Dynamically list the values

    <#list test.banana?values as v>
    ${v}
    </#list>

Dynamically list the keys and values

    <#list test.banana as k,v >
    ${k}: ${v}
    </#list>
```

I hope you can access the banana json in any of the 3 ways said above and achieve your objective.

Reference: https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_hash.html and  https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_list.html#ref.directive.list

Tested in https://try.freemarker.apache.org/